# How to replace special elements such as '?',etc to html entity number

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP URL encoding retaining invalid url characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020234/php-url-encoding-retaining-invalid-url-characters)

I use a form similiar below in admin panel . Where admin can login and post status(uses both database and file system).

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
Title : <input type="text" name="title">
Content : <textarea name="status" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
</form>
```

In post.php

```
$title = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['title']));
```

If an admin posts a status. A folder will be create with the entered title and the title name is stored in mysql database. But when an admin use Special characters like "?" , the url is encoded something like this `http://example.com/title?` and it shows 404 not found. So how can i replace special characters of title element to entity number.

***It will be helpful if the answer is in php***

Comment: You are looking for [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) (that's PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

$title = trim(strip_tags($_POST['title']));

followed by

urlencode($title);

Should do what you need.

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: This works but i just want to change only 2 to 3 charecter like ?,', .  so  i use str_replace. But i will try urlencode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with this code `$title = str_replace("?","",$title)`

Comment: That would straight up remove them.  What the poster wanted was the html entity form.  For example, `?` would become `&#63;`.