# Is there a way in PHP to encode special characters so they can be used in an URL?

Tags: php, url, aes, encode

I have a string that comes from an AES encryption like this -> "‚±«~—ÄÔý 3ƒÛœÛ"
Is there a way to encode this string so it can be transmitted to a script via URL?

Thank You!

Comment: You mean a function like `urlencode()`?

Comment: urlencode is not working because when i decode the string with urldecode() it doesnt give me the original string which was encoded with urlencode. edit: Same for base64

Comment: rawurlencode(), then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP URL encoding retaining invalid url characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020234/php-url-encoding-retaining-invalid-url-characters)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use urlencode or base64_encode for that task, both will produce url safe strings

Comment: echo urldecode(urlencode("‚±«~—ÄÔý 3ƒÛœÛ")) -> â€šÂ±Â«~â€”Ã„Ã”Ã½ 3Æ’Ã›Å“Ã› echo base64_decode(base64_encode("‚±«~—ÄÔý 3ƒÛœÛ")) -> â€šÂ±Â«~â€”Ã„Ã”Ã½ 3Æ’Ã›Å“Ã›

Comment: Problem solved! Was a not a problem of the functions but the enconding between client and server!

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

Use the global function

```
urlencode($string)
```

If you want to get the original paramters you can decode the URL-Parameters with:

```
urldecode($string)
```

Comment: mhh, I don't think it will work with urlencode... Here is what the string will look like after urldecode -> "â€šÂ±Â«~â€”Ã„Ã”Ã½ 3Æ’Ã›Å“Ã›"

Comment: You don't need to decode it if you actually transmit if via URL. The problem that you describe is another: client and server seem to use different character encodings.

Comment: Sure, decode was just for example, do you have an idea how to bypass the problem with the character encodings?