# PHP url string with special character

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a url which looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com?id=1&user=Test&name=Test23423&country=us
```

If the url is like this, it works fine. But some user uses special characters (for example "&") like this:

```
http://www.example.com?id=1&user=Te&st&name=Test&123&country=us
```

How can i convert this string, that everything works fine at the end?

Comment: Can you give me an example on my links?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way in PHP to encode special characters so they can be used in an URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011680/is-there-a-way-in-php-to-encode-special-characters-so-they-can-be-used-in-an-url)

Answer (score 1):

First use your anchor tag something like this:

```
<a href="try.php/?id=1&user=<?php echo urlencode('Te&st'); ?>&name=<?php echo urlencode('Te&st'); ?>">Click Here</a>
```

And on other page get value something like this:

```
echo $_GET['user'];
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: You don't need to `urldecode` `$_GET`, it's already decoded by PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
echo $test=urlencode('http://www.example.com?id=1&user=Test&name='.htmlspecialchars('Test&123').'&country=us');
echo "<br />";
echo urldecode($test);
```

You can create function like below just to check for "&". If you want function for all special characters then do let me know.

```
$test = 'http://www.example.com?id=1&user=Te&st&name=Test&123&country=us';
foreach (explode("&", $test) as $key => $item) {
    if (strpos($item, "=") === FALSE) {
        $arr[$key - 1].="&" . $item;
    } else {
        $arr[$key] = $item;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: The problem is, that i receive this string and i can´t change the link before i receive it. Do you understand what i mean? I think i have to cut the string on the right places before i can go on.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` uses `&` as a special character! It's useless in this context.

Comment: @Sven If you receive the URL with the non-encoded `&`, there's not really much you can do. It's completely arbitrary what that URL means now. It ***must*** be correctly encoded *before*, you can't unambiguously fix it after the fact.

Comment: @deceze The url looks like this - is there anything i can do? http://www.example.com/iosl/include/apns.php?task=register&appname=TrackQuiz&appversion=5.51&deviceuid=49E0BD77&devicetoken=12345&devicename=Sven%2520iPhone%25206%2520&%2520Test&devicemodel=iPhone&deviceversion=8.4&pushbadge=enabled&pushalert=enabled&pushsound=enabled&country=DE

Answer (score -1):

Use this function i think it heplp you :

```
function seo_friendly_url($string){
    $string = str_replace(array('[\', \']'), '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/U', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;/i', '-', $string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    $string = preg_replace('/&([a-z])(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig|quot|rsquo);/i', '\\1', $string );
    $string = preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '/[-]+/') , '-', $string);
    return strtolower(trim($string, '-'));
}
```

Then you need to encode a user name like this:

```
seo_friendly_url($test) ;
```